# Fallo en guardar datos en una Estructura Dinamica

Tags: c, punteros

Quiero crear una estructura que cresca de tamaño al registrar un nuevo dato.
Me guarda los tres primeros datos bien sin ningun problema, al ingresar un   cuarto dato se borra el primer dato hasta ingresar un septimo dato se borra el segundo.

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct{
  char *nombre;
  char *apellido;
}datos;

datos *dato;

void memDatos(int *tmx);
void reDatos(int *x);
void delSpace(char word[50]);
void memDinamic(char aux[50],int w, int d);
void editarDatos(int tmx);

int main(){
  int op;
  char key;
  int tmx = 0;
  memDatos(&tmx);// asignar tamanio de la estructura

  do{
     do{
        printf("\n  Digite un Comando;\n");
        printf("(1) Registrar Datos\n");
        printf("(2) Iniciar Busqueda\n");
        printf("(3) Editar Datos\n >>> ");
        scanf("%d",&op);
     }while(op < 1 || op > 3);

     switch(op){
        case 1: reDatos(&tmx); break;
    //  case 2: busqueda(tmx); break;
        case 3: editarDatos(tmx); break;
     }

     printf("\nTarea Finalizada\nDesea continuar (S/N) ");
     fflush(stdin);
     scanf("%c",&key);
  }while(key == 's' || key == 'S');


  system("pause>null");
  return 0;
}

void memDatos(int *tmx){

 dato = (datos*)malloc((*tmx+1)*sizeof(datos));// se registra el tamanio
 if(dato == NULL) exit(1);

}

void reDatos(int *x){  
 char auxiliar[50];
 int d=1;

  printf("Nombre?: "); fflush(stdin);
  fgets(auxiliar, 50, stdin);
  delSpace(auxiliar); // eliminar el salto de linea de fgets
  memDinamic(auxiliar,*x,d); d++; // asignar el tamanio adecuado para nombre
  printf("Apellido?: "); fflush(stdin);
  fgets(auxiliar, 50, stdin); 
  delSpace(auxiliar); memDinamic(auxiliar,*x,d);// x es la posicion a acceder en la estructura
  (*x)++; // incrementar el tamanio de estructura
}

void delSpace(char word[50]){  
 int i;  
 for(i = 0; i < 50; i++){
    if(word[i] == '\n'){  
        word[i] = '\0';  
      }  
  }  
}

void memDinamic(char aux[50],int x, int d){
  switch(d){
    case 1: dato[x].nombre = (char*)malloc((strlen(aux)+1)*sizeof(char));
            strcpy(dato[x].nombre,aux); break;
    default: dato[x].apellido = (char*)malloc((strlen(aux)+1)*sizeof(char));  
            strcpy(dato[x].apellido,aux); break;
 }

}

void editarDatos(int tmx){  
  int i;  
  puts("Usuarios registrados, seleccione alguno para continuar\n");  
  for(i = 0; i < tmx; i++){  
      printf("(%i) %s %s\n",i+1,dato[i].nombre,dato[i].apellido);  
   }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fíjate en lo que haces:

```
void memDatos( int *tmx ){
  dato = (datos*)malloc((*tmx+1)*sizeof(datos));// se registra el tamanio
  if(dato == NULL) exit(1);
}
```

A esa función la llamas **una sola vez** así: `memDatos(&tmx);`

Con eso, reservas memoria para **1 solo instancia** de tu `struct datos`.

Sin embargo, luego haces:

```
void memDinamic(char aux[50],int x, int d){
  switch(d){
  case 1:
    dato[x].nombre = (char*)malloc((strlen(aux)+1)*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(dato[x].nombre,aux);
    break;

    default:
      dato[x].apellido = (char*)malloc((strlen(aux)+1)*sizeof(char));  
      strcpy(dato[x].apellido,aux);
      break;
   }
}
```

Fíjate en lo importante: haces **`dato[x]`**.

Ese es tu problema: tratas `datos` como si fuera una *formación* o *arreglo* de tamaño `x` ... cuando en realidad **es de tamaño fijo 1**.

Una posible solución sería:

```
void reDatos(int *x){  
  char auxiliar[50];
  int d=1;

  if( *x ) {
    datos = (struct datos *)realloc( datos, sizeof( struct datos ) * ( ( *x ) + 1 ) );
    if( !datos ) exit( 1 );
  }

  printf("Nombre?: "); fflush(stdin);
  fgets(auxiliar, 50, stdin);
  delSpace(auxiliar); // eliminar el salto de linea de fgets
  memDinamic(auxiliar,*x,d); d++; // asignar el tamanio adecuado para nombre
  printf("Apellido?: "); fflush(stdin);
  fgets(auxiliar, 50, stdin); 
  delSpace(auxiliar); memDinamic(auxiliar,*x,d);// x es la posicion a acceder en la estructura
  (*x)++; // incrementar el tamanio de estructura
}
```

Con ese cambio, antes de añadir elementos, **redimensionamos** tu *formación*, añadiendo espacio para 1 elemento mas.

<sub>**Nota**: No lo he probado, pero, salvo algún detalle mínimo, debería funcionar.</sub>